# Пиетет: иметь или испытывать?

Tags: выбор-слова, словоупотребление

Вопрос, собственно, в заголовке.
Имеется цитата

> К этому человеку все относились с большим пиететом.
>
> *Аркадий Стругацкий, Борис Стругацкий, «Понедельник начинается в субботу», 1964 г.*

Значит, "иметь"?

offtopic: какой тэг здесь подойдёт лучше всего? Как называется то чем я сейчас занимаюсь, выбирая из `иметь` и `испытывать` относительно `пиетет`а? Семантическое согласование? о_О

Похоже, этот вопрос меня интересует даже сильнее заданного ранее. А вот `интересует`: `больше` или/и `сильнее`?)

Comment: http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?game=x&all=x&word=%EF%E8%E5%F2%E5%F2

Comment: Сочетаемость. Так это называется. В словарях после значения обычно даются словосочетания /collocations.

Comment: насчёт тэга согласен с @V.V., существует "Словарь сочетаемости слов русского языка"

Answer (score 4):

Это вопрос не семантики, а стиля и принятого употребления в речи. И то, и другое может со временем изменяться, "дрейфовать". И некоторые речевые обороты, хоть формально и возможны, но практически "не существуют", т.е. не используются.

Так что: пиетет не "имеют", а "как бы "применяют" к отношению, ну и "испытывать пиетет" это несколько неуклюже, а лучше: "испытывать (глубокое) уважение"; "пиететом "обладает" отношение (к лицу)".

Второй вопрос не имеет определённого ответа. Оба варианта правильны, и выбирать следует по вкусу. :)

Answer (score 1):

*`Испытывать`* и *`иметь`* семантически отличаются, поэтому не думаю, что их следует противопоставлять. В моём понимании *`испытывать`* может описывать нечто сиюминутное, преходящее, в то время как *`иметь`* - нечто постоянное, долговременное.

Поэтому *`испытывать пиетет`* - это скорее испытывать его в некий момент времени или в определённых обстоятельствах, например во время общения, а *`иметь пиетет`* - это быть готовым к его испытанию априори, быть наделённым способностью испытывать пиетет по отношению к человеку.

Так же и с *`больше`* против *`сильнее`*. Уместны оба.